# Get an Entity items in a Symfony Form

Tags: php, symfony

I have an Entity of Choice, I need to get its attributs in 1 label.. As the following example :

```
+---+-------+--------+--------------+
|   | price |  count | deliveryDate |
+---+-------+--------+--------------+
| X |  100  |    6   | 2015-01-02   |
+---+-------+--------+--------------+
|   |   70  |    5   | 2015-02-03   |
+---+-------+--------+--------------+
```

How can I get the entity items in symfony? this is my form type :

**FormType.php :**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('Age')
        ->add('message', MessageType::class)
        ->add('choice', EntityType::class, array('class'=>'EspBundle\Entity\Choice',
            'multiple'=>true,
            'expanded'=>true,
            'query_builder'=> function(EntityRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.name','ASC');},
            ))
        ->add('Save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

How could be my twig file then? I tried to get them using `{{form.label(form.choice.name)}}` , but it is not working !

**EDIT 1 :** Here is the result I get [image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest route here is just set the choice_label option on the field.  So:

```
->add('choice', EntityType::class, array('class'=>'EspBundle\Entity\Choice',
        'multiple'=>true,
        'expanded'=>true,
        'query_builder'=> function(EntityRepository $er){
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.name','ASC');},
        'choice_label' => 'name'
        ))
```

In twig you can just render it as {{form_widget(form.choice) }} or just the entire form out as {{ form_widget(form)  }}

Comment: I made what u said, but it doesn't appears as I've mentionned before, see the edit of my question please

Comment: Do one of your entities have the "name" test1 and test2 ?  In your example it doesn't look like the choice entity even has a name column so I'd expect you'd want to output a different field?